# Use colum to define keys using mysqli_fetch_all

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have a query that acquires information about gallery categories from a database and loads it into an array for use in several places throughout a script.

```
$q_gals = "SELECT `gal_id`, `gal_name` FROM `cms_galleries` ORDER BY `gal_sort` ASC, `gal_id` DESC";
$r_gals = $dbc->query($q_gals);
if (($r_gals) && ($r_gals->num_rows > 0)) {
    $galleries = $r_gals->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
}
```

I would prefer to have the keys of the `$galleries` array to be the `gal_id` value from the query. I know I can do this simply by iterating through the result with a `while` loop and manually build the array as I want it:

```
$galleries = array();
while($row_gal = $r_gal->fetch_assoc()) {
  $galleries[$row_gal['gal_id']] = $row_gal['gal_name'];
}
```

And to be honest, it's mostly the tidier code that `fetch_all` gives me that makes me want to do this. This isn't a massive script any performance difference between the two is irrelevant. I could, I suppose loop through the existing array and update the keys with the `gal_id` value, but this seems self-defeating.

Is this wishful thinking on my part? Or is there some obscure trick that would accomplish this?

Comment: If you only want gal_id then you can replace query by adding GROUP_CONCAT(gal_id) in SELECT statement that will give only one row with comma separated field value.

Comment: No, I want both the `gal_id` and the `gal_name` columns, just with the `gal_id` as the key for the array and `gal_name` as the value.

Comment: Please check Example #3 section in following link :
http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetchall.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im going to make some assumptions here, the first and most important is that you're using PHP 5.5 or above, and the second is that you're just looking to avoid the for loop and not actually do some SQL magic...

To achieve this in just one line of code you need to use a couple of easily missed PHP array functions; [array_column()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) and [array_combine()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php).

The code in place of your for loop would then look like this:

```
$galleries = array_combine(array_column($galleries, 'gal_id'), $galleries);
```

The array_columns() call creates an array from the defined column, so you end up with an array containing just the 'gal_id' values. Then array_combine() merges the first array with the second array using the first array as the array key values.

Comment: It's on a shared server, but I can set it to run PHP 5.5. I shall try this. Thanks.